# Adding a parameter when calling a View struct in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to add a function call in Swift view? I'm hoping to make a function that receives a URL when a certain NavigationView is clicked so it is able to pull elements from the json in hopes to show all data. For example,

```
NavigationLink(destination: AllStoriesView(URL: "json url here")) {
    ZStack {
       Image("allstories-newsource")
       Text("TOP NEWS")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `URL` as attribute to the view in order to pass it as parameter at initialization.

```
struct AllStoriesView: View {
    var URL: String

    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}
```

or make it `private` and create an `init` function:

```
struct AllStoriesView: View {
    private var URL: String

    init(URL: String) {
        self.URL = URL
    }

    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i do this without initializing the URL in the beginning?

Comment: @piximi, make it optional, like `var URL: String?`